# how to set a value to an xml element in java code in android?

Tags: android

I have a edit_text field in activity_X.xml. I have a button B in activty_X.xml. On clicking button B i need to assign a value to edit_text field. How to do?

Comment: It is basic in android. Study the basics first and it will answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

you should try something on your own then post any question if you are getting any problem in that...anyways here's how you can implement this

```
Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
           EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textidinxml);
         editText1.setText("Some text to show on edittext");                    
    }
});
```